# Updating Child Component when using trackBy

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I have a list of items which I apply a stagger animation to. I use `trackBy` so that the entry animations don't repeat when I make updates to the items (e.g. changing name / bookmarking).

I can update the name and the changes appear, but when I update the 'bookmarked' status - I can see no change. The item updates, but it's just not rendered.

I've simplified the template code:

list.html :

```
<div class="list" *ngIf="projects" @list>
  <div *ngFor="let item of itemList; trackBy: trackByFn" [@items]="itemList.length">
    <list-item [item]="item" (bookmark)="onBookmark($event)"></list-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

list-item.html :

```
<div class="item">

  <div class="bookmark" (click)="emitBookmark()">
    // this doesn't change
    <i class="fa-bookmark" [ngClass]="item.metadata.bookmarked ? 'fas' : 'far'"></i>
  </div>

  // this updates, no problem
  <div class="name">{{ item.name }}</div>

</div>
```

I've been searching for ages and can't seem to find a solution. ChangeDetection strategies don't seem to help.

Comment: Please add StackBlitz example

Comment: can you show **list-item.ts** file too.

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate the issue in StackBlitz, so I'm gonna have to disable the animations and come back to it later. If I can replicate, I'll link the StackBlitz and add additional info.